# VBA Hide Rows that contain N/A

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, office365, microsoft-excel-365

I have an excel file that has dynamic data that changes daily. For example, a user will populate data on the data tab and the percentages are calculated using an "if Command" if there isnt any data N/A is populated in the cell. (screenshot) 
I'd like to add a macro that will hide any rows that contain cells with N/A This is what I am using and I either delete the rows or it hides all rows. Depending on the value I set. 
"N" removes all rows N/A doesn't do anything. I have checked other examples but i couldnt get any others to work.

Thank you in advance!

```
Sub HideRows()
BeginRow = 9
EndRow = 50
ChkCol = 20

For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow
If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = "N/A" Then
Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
Else
Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
Next RowCnt
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: You compare `Value = Na Then` but strings should be enclosed in `"` making it : `Value = "Na" Then` but then your screenshot shows `Na` as `N/A`. Which is it?

Comment: Hey, Thanks for replying. So it's actually N/A i was playing around with different commands and would get an error would i used N/A, however i put the brackets in and no error. However, the macro still doesn't work. Here is what I am using now..

Comment: **Code looked weird here so i updated the main post

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but this is the formula in the cell "=IFERROR(MIN(100%,J15/L15),"N/A")"

but I did just type N/A in a cell to see if the formula was causing a problem. Macro still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish this using the Tip from andreas and a new code I found. This was the final product.

```
Sub Hide_E()
Dim LastRow As Long, c As Range
Application.EnableEvents = False
LastRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
On Error Resume Next
For Each c In Range("E1:E" & LastRow)
   If c.Value = "N/A" Then
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf c.Value = 1 Then
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
Next
On Error GoTo 0
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Thank you for your help!